# error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'

Tags: java

Not sure what is wrong here is the line that wrong.

```
if((board[z][i] = 1) && (board[z][i++] = 1) && (board[z++][i] = 1)){
```

Here is my whole code not finished:

```
public class Solution {

 static void nextMove(int player, int [][] board){

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int player;
    int board[][] = new int[8][8];

    //If player is 1, I'm the first player.
    //If player is 2, I'm the second player.
    player = in.nextInt();

    //Read the board now. The board is a 8x8 array filled with 1 or 0.
  for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++){
      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          board[(z)][(i)] = in.nextInt();
         }
  }for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++){
       for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
           if((board[z][i] = 1) && (board[z][i++] = 1) && (board[z++][i] = 1)){
               System.out.print(z + " " + i);
        }
    }
  }
    nextMove(player,board);

}
}
```

Comment: You should also do "i+1" and "z+1", I don't think you want the side-effects of "++" (also you're doing post-increment, when pre-increment would be slightly more correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the relational operator == instead of =. Each of the 3 sub-statements within the parentheses of your if statement should represent a boolean. In Java, = is used to assign a value and == is used to check equality. Therefore, you must change your if statement to:

```
if((board[z][i] == 1) && (board[z][i++] == 1) && (board[z++][i] == 1)){
```

Also, rather than incrementing z and i by 1 (because you are already doing that as part of your for loop), maybe make i++ --> i + 1 and z++ --> z + 1.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
if((board[z][i] ==1) && (board[z][i++] == 1) && (board[z++][i] == 1)){
```

use double equals for comparing. I think you have missed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the assignment operator, when you should be comparing them.

```
if((board[z][i] == 1) && (board[z][i++] == 1) && (board[z++][i] == 1)){
```

Comment: Thanks you. Should of realized that myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((board[z][i] = 1) && (board[z][i++] = 1) && (board[z++][i] = 1)) //Yes this line is wrong
```

You are using **'='** at `(board[z][i] = 1)` `(board[z][i++] = 1)` `(board[z++][i] = 1)` at these comparisons. You need to use **'=='** operand for comparison.

An **'='** operator is used for assigning the values to the variables whereas **'=='** is used for comparison. 
Just to add one more point, when comparing values of two **Strings** you have to use **.equals()** method as **'=='** compares by reference in Java on objects.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your code be

`if((board[z][i] == 1) && (board[z][i++] == 1) && (board[z++][i] == 1)){`

emphasizing the **==** issue

Answer (score 1):

You used the assignment (=) operator instead of checking if they were equal. The equality is checked with == operator.
Try this instead

```
if((board[z][i] ==1) && (board[z][i++] == 1) && (board[z++][i] == 1)){
```