# bad operand types for binary operator '&&'

Tags: java

Not sure what is wrong here. This line `if (ocean[row][col]==null && ocean2[row][col] = null)`. I tried `((ocean[row][col])==null && (ocean2[row][col]) = null)`. Still it's wrong. What is the issue?

```
public static void deployCompShips(String[][] ocean) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Computer is deploying ships");
            while (compShips < 5) {
                int col = rand.nextInt(10);
                int row = rand.nextInt(10);
    
                if (ocean[row][col]==null && ocean2[row][col] = null) {
                    System.out.println((compShips+1)+". ship DEPLOYED");
                    ocean2[row][col] = "@";
                    compShips++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120805/error-bad-operand-types-for-binary-operator

Comment: You forgot an `=` sign between `ocean2[row][col]` and `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use assignment operator to compare two values.

```
                                              
if (ocean[row][col]==null && ocean2[row][col] = null) 
                                              ^
                                              |
                                      using assignment operator
```